# Module vs methods outside module

Tags: ruby, methods, module

I would like to know what the difference is between using a module with methods inside it and using a simple file with many methods without creating a module, like the example below:

```
def doStuff
  puts 'test';
end

module Example
  def self.doStuff
    puts 'test';
  end
end
```

I could require both files and use the methods inside one. I want to know why I should create a module instead of having just a bunch of methods inside a `.rb` file.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Got it, I will consider your advise. Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modules allow you group your methods and you can include them in other modules and classes. You can include module methods into the module/class itself or its eigenclass. So, with modules you have more flexibility. Not to mention that you are not cluttering up the "global" namespace.

Also, when you define method in a file, you are defining it in the current context. Since, everything in Ruby is an object, you are actually defining it within a `main` object (an instance of `Object` class).

```
2.3.0 :001 > self
 => main 
2.3.0 :002 > self.class
 => Object 
2.3.0 :003 > self.object_id
 => 70123533022000 
2.3.0 :004 > def test; end;
2.3.0 :005 > self.public_methods.include? :test
 => true
```

Comment: That's all I needed, thanks for the explanation and the fast response!

Comment: Methods defined on the top-level are not defined within the `main` object. They are defined as private instance methods of `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's find out.

```
module M
  def a; end
end

File.write("temp.rb", "def b\nputs 'hi'\nend") #=> 19
require_relative 'temp.rb'

class C
  include M
end

C.instance_methods & [:a, :b]                  #=> [:a] 
C.private_instance_methods & [:a, :b]          #=> [:b] 
C.instance_method(:b).owner                    #=> Object 

Object.instance_methods.include? :b            #=> false 
Object.private_instance_methods.include? :b    #=> true 

Object.send(:public, :b)                       #=> Object 
Object.instance_methods.include? :b            #=> true 
Object.private_instance_methods.include? :b    #=> false

C.instance_methods & [:a, :b]                  #=> [:a, :b] 
C.private_instance_methods & [:a, :b]          #=> [] 
C.new.b                                        #=> hi
```

The results are the same if we write:

```
class C
  include M
  require_relative 'temp.rb'
end
```